# rewriterule or alias in apache config for folder to root change

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm changing my Drupal site from www.example.com/demo to www.example.com. The resources like js, css etc still lives under "demo" folder. What should be the Rewriterule or Alias that is required to achieve this change?

I currently have this setting in my .htaccess file

> Options +FollowSymlinks
>   RewriteEngine On
>   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
>   RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
>   RewriteRule ^ - [L]
>   RewriteRule ^ /

Comment: why don't you copy that resources outside the demo folder?

Comment: there are other folders outside and for better organization of large number of files within the demo folder, i want to keep it inside the folder.

Answer (score 0):

You should have these rules to test whether the files exist to the demo folder, and rewrite the URL if it does.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/demo%{REQUEST_URI} -f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.js|\.css)$
RewriteRule ^(.*) /demo/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Line 1: Test if the request file not exists in root folder

Line 2: Test if the request file exists in demo folder

Line 3: Test if the request file end with js / css extensions (change to suit your case)

Line 4: Rewrite the URL to request the file inside the demo folder

Comment: Looks good, one bit that want to be clarified is, would these conditions look for index.html file which is present in the parent folder of "demo" folder and look for js, css, fonts etc within the demo folder and at the same time remove the "demo" from the url?

Comment: Also if somebody uses the url  www.example.com/demo, he should be automatically directed to www.example.com

Comment: you should modify the rules to suit your case, the above rules only look for the files' extension that ends with js / css